# JsonParseException: Unexpected character

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controllers

I'm trying to pass an entity together with two string values from the html page to the server, but I'm getting this error.

controller.js:

```
'use strict';

myApp.controller('fooController',
function($scope,fooCollection) {
    $scope.fooEntity = {

    };
    $scope.createfooGroup = function() {
        fooCollection.createfooGroup($scope.fooEntity ,
            $scope.string1, $scope.string2
        )
    };
});
```

service.js:

```
myApp.factory('fooCollection', function($resource) {
return $resource('../api/group', {}, {
    createfooGroup : {method: 'POST'}
})
});
```

And the entire error message is:

```
Failed executing POST /group
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('a' (code 97)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@4845afdc; line: 1, column: 2]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:183)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:89)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:112)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:296)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:250)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:237)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have added ng-model attributes on the webpage. Can someone help me out with this?? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a method of a `$resource` instance, even a custom one, it accepts a strict list of parameters. Here is a quote from the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource):

> The action methods on the class object or instance object can be
>   invoked with the following parameters:
>
> - HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success],
>     [error])
> - non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters],
>     postData, [success], [error])
> - non-GET instance actions:
>     instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])

Your custom method `createfooGroup` is explicitly defined as a `POST` method, so the second option is applied (*non-GET "class" actions*). Action expects that the first argument `[parameters]` would be a list of query string parameters which is optional, the second `postData` - required for `POST` methods, the third `[success]` - callback for success, which is also optional.

So, when you make a call

```
fooCollection.createfooGroup($scope.fooEntity, $scope.string1, $scope.string2);
```

you pass `$scope.fooEntity` as `[parameters]`, `$scope.string1` as `postData` and `$scope.string2` as `[success]`, which obviously will lead to some unexpected behavior. In this case you server recieves value of `$scope.string2` as a POST data, which I assume is just some string and not a valid JSON, therefore server can't parse it. If you want to pass all you values to server, put them in array, so an action would interpret it as a `postData`:

```
fooCollection.createfooGroup([$scope.fooEntity, $scope.string1, $scope.string2]);
```